# ubuntu not detecting CDdrives

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

Ihave insatlled ubuntu 10.4 on my compuer with 6 cd drives.
Now initiallyi had window server 2008 and i had to install marvel raid  sata controller  and then my window detected all 6 drives.

Now ubuntu is detecting only 3 drives and i have not found marvell drivers for ubuntu bt i have drives for window 2008.

Now my question is if i have vrtual machine inside ubuntu using vmware workstation and i install that driver. then can VM dtect thse 6 drives or host has to detect those drives first  to make VMs use that

Ubuntu shows this thing from terminal

```
*-cdrom:0               
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GSA-H10N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom2
       logical name: /dev/cdrw2
       logical name: /dev/dvd2
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw2
       logical name: /dev/scd0
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: JL10
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-cdrom:1
       description: DVD writer
       product: DVDRRW GWA-4164B
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/scd1
       logical name: /dev/sr1
       version: 1.01
       serial: [HL-DT-STDVDRRW GWA-4164B1.0105/05/12
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Is t detecting all drives or thise local names just same

Answer (score 2):

The guest OS does not use drivers for devices on the host unless the device is explicitly passed through at the hardware level, such as a USB device. If the host cannot see the device at all then the guest will not either.